# How to write a class library in c++ like the one we write for functions

Tags: c++, class, static-libraries

Suppose we need to write a library of functions which we intend to use in our programs, then we could write it by the following way.

In a .h file we declare the function (mylibrary could be any file name we wish)
Assuming sum is the function we wish to have in our library

```
int sum(int x, int y);
```

Then we will have a .cpp file which will define the function as follows :

```
#include "mylibrary.h"

int sum(int x, int y){ return x+y; }
```

Now we we wish to use this function in our programs, say myprog.cpp, we could use like this :

```
#include
#include "mylibrary.h"

int main()
{
cout<<sum(10,20)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

My question is that can we do something similar for classes as we did for functions, i.e.

Can we declare classes in a .h file like :

```
class X;
class Y;
```

Then define the class in .cpp like :

```
#include"myclasses.h"
class X
{
public:
int m;
};

class Y
{
public:
int n;
};
```

and then use these classes in our program, say myprog.cpp, like this :

```
#include"myclasses.h"

int main()
{
class X myX;
myX.m = 0;
return 0;
}
```

I tried this and got Error aggregate 'X myX' has incomplete type and cannot be defined.

If I put entire definition in myclasses.h file, then it runs fine without errors.

Comment: Please show some code. Because yes, you can declare classes in header files and write their implementation in a corresponding cpp file.

Comment: We don't know `x` from the dark side of the moon. *Post your code with your question* and *clearly* mark where the errors happen. And the *exact* text of the errors is important; don't summarize the message.

Comment: @UnholySheep & WhozCraig : tnx for ur responses. I'll keep this in mind while posting any questions next time :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put all of the *methods* in the `.cpp` file, but you have to have a "complete" declaration of the *class* in the header file.  That is, you can do this:

```
// X.h
#ifndef _X_H
#define _X_H

class X {
    int data;
    void internal_method();

public:
    void foo();
    void bar();
};

#endif // X.h
```

and then you can define `X::foo`, `X::bar`, and `X::internal_method` in a `.cpp` file, but you can't do this or anything like it:

```
// X.h
#ifndef _X_H
#define _X_H

// This code is incorrect and will not even compile
class X;
public void X::foo();
public void X::bar();

#endif // X.h
```

This is a fundamental limitation of C++, and yes, it means you can't change the data members or add or remove methods - even private methods - without recompiling everything.  The [pimpl hack](https://tonka2013.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/why-every-c-developer-should-know-about-the-pimpl-idiom-pattern/) works around this, but has its own problems.

(You may have noticed that `class X;` all by itself *is* a valid thing to write.  That is an "incomplete" declaration of the class, which allows you to declare things involving *pointers* and *references* to X objects, but not X objects themselves.  For instance, this header file *is* valid:

```
// Y.h
#ifndef _Y_H
#define _Y_H

class X;

class Y {
   X& ex;

public:
    Y(X& ex) : ex(ex) {}

    void foo();
    void bar(X& fx);
};

#endif // Y.h
```

This can be a useful thing to do, for instance to cut down on the number of header files that need to include other header files, and to break mutual dependency loops (imagine if `class X` had some methods that took reference-to-Y arguments, without a feature like this you couldn't write that at all).)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this; *but* the complete declaration of a class — analogous to declaring a function — involves declaring all of its members. (See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class for details, though I gather that you're already familiar with them.)

If you simply "forward declare" the class, by writing `class Foo;` without fully declaring it, then you can still pass around pointers to it, but you can't refer to any of its members, including its constructors (even the compiler-generated ones, because those aren't *unconditionally* generated; not all classes have them). Note that a forward declaration isn't even enough to tell the compiler how big an instance will be (`sizeof`).